# SharedPreferencesBackupHelper for an offline application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service, backup-agent

I am trying to keep a back up of the sharedPreference for my app that works only offline. I was planning to use **SharedPreferencesBackupHelper** and **BackupAgentHelper** API of android but it seems that these api enables the app to back up the shared preference only on cloud and not locally to the device.

I want to know if these apis keep a back up locally also or not. If not , then is there any other way by which I can keep a backup of my sharedPreference file locally on the device so that when the user uninstalls the app, The sharedPreference file remains untouched.

Comment: You can create you own backup mechanism to do. All your backup share preferences stored in sdcard.

Comment: @alijandro so does it mean that SharedPreferencesBackupHelper and BackupAgentHelper can not  back up the shared preference offline?

Comment: Yes, the default implementation is backup to the remote server. You have to implement you own if you want to backup offline or locally.